# Update table with case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to update multiple columns using case statement, I achieved this but it is not a best way i have to do same task three times, how can i achieve in one statement here is my test sql script:

```
 Delimiter //
create procedure test_f()
begin
update test set 
    #### total####
        test.total = case when test.currencyid='INR' then  test.total/85.09
        Else test.total End,
        test.total = case when test.currencyid='SEK' then  test.total/8.97
        Else test.total End,

    ### Commission ####
        test.commission = case when test.currencyid='INR' then  test.commission/85.09
        Else test.commission End,
        test.commission = case when test.currencyid='SEK' then  test.commission/8.97
        Else test.commission End,


        test.currencyid = case when test.currencyid in ('SEK','INR') then  'EUR'
        Else test.currencyid End


WHERE test.currencyid in ('SEK','INR') ;
END //
```

Now i want to update all three columns altogether based on currencyid.

Comment: i want to update total, commission and currency such as update table test set commission = 123, total= 123, currencyid ='EUR' where currencyid= 'other than euro'

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for the first case:
instead of:

```
update test set 
#### total####
    test.total = case when test.currencyid='INR' then  test.total/85.09
    Else test.total End,
    test.total = case when test.currencyid='SEK' then  test.total/8.97
    Else test.total End,
```

change to:

```
update test set 
#### total####
    test.total = 
      case when test.currencyid='INR' then  test.total/85.09
           when test.currencyid='SEK' then  test.total/8.97
      Else test.total 
      End,
```

do the same for `### Commission ####`

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write the query as:

```
update test t 
        set t.total = t.total / (case when t.currencyid = 'INR' then 85.09 else 8.97 end),
            t.commission = t.commission / (case when t.currencyid = 'INR' then 85.09 else 8.97 end),
            t.currency = 'EUR'
    where t.currencyid in ('INR', 'SEK') ;
```

The `where` clause limits the currencies to the two mentioned, so the `case` only has to test for those two conditions.  Simplifying the case statement also makes it clearer that the same logic is being used for both calculations.